# Python pandas - how to group close elements

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe where I need to group elements with distance of no more than 1. 
For example, if this is my df:

```
     group_number  val
0              1    5
1              1    8
2              1   12
3              1   13
4              1   22
5              1   26
6              1   31
7              2    7
8              2   16
9              2   17
10             2   19
11             2   29
12             2   33
13             2   62
```

So I need to group both by the `group_number` and `val` where the values of `val` are smaller than or equal to 1.

So, in this example, lines `2` and `3` would group together, and also lines `8` and `9` would group together.

I tried using diff or related functions, but I didn't figure it out.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `diff` is the right approach - just combine it with `gt` and `cumsum` and you have your groups.

The idea is to use cumulative sum for differences bigger than your threshold. Difference larger than your threshold will become `True`. In contrast, differences equal or lower to your threshold will become `False`. Cumulatively summing over the boolean values will leave differences equal or lower to your threshold unchanged and hence they get the same group number.

```
max_distance = 1

df["group_diff"] = df.sort_values("val")\
                     .groupby("group_number")["val"]\
                     .diff()\
                     .gt(max_distance)\
                     .cumsum()

print(df)

    group_number    val group_diff
0   1               5   0
1   1               8   1
2   1               12  2
3   1               13  2
4   1               22  5
5   1               26  6
6   1               31  8
7   2               7   0
8   2               16  3
9   2               17  3
10  2               19  4
11  2               29  7
12  2               33  9
13  2               62  10
```

You can now use `groupby` on *group_number* and *group_diff* and see the resulting groups with the following:

```
grouped = df.groupby(["group_number", "group_diff"])
print(grouped.groups)

{(1, 0): Int64Index([0], dtype='int64'),
 (1, 1): Int64Index([1], dtype='int64'),
 (1, 2): Int64Index([2, 3], dtype='int64'),
 (1, 5): Int64Index([4], dtype='int64'),
 (1, 6): Int64Index([5], dtype='int64'),
 (1, 8): Int64Index([6], dtype='int64'),
 (2, 0): Int64Index([7], dtype='int64'),
 (2, 3): Int64Index([8, 9], dtype='int64'),
 (2, 4): Int64Index([10], dtype='int64'),
 (2, 7): Int64Index([11], dtype='int64'),
 (2, 9): Int64Index([12], dtype='int64'),
 (2, 10): Int64Index([13], dtype='int64')}
```

Thanks @jezrael for the hint of avoiding a new column to increase performance:

```
group_diff = df.sort_values("val")\
               .groupby("group_number")["val"]\
               .diff()\
               .gt(max_distance)\
               .cumsum()

grouped = df.groupby(["group_number", group_diff])
```

Comment: Thank you! but you assume that `val` values are sorted - and they don't have to be. Please edit your answer a bit and I will happily accept it.

Comment: @BinyaminEven That's why I put `sort_values("val")` in the expression to guard against unsorted values (unlike your example here).

Comment: but you have to sort also by the `group number`. I would edit it to `.sort_values(by=['group_number','val'])`. (In that case you won't get, in this example, that line 7 will be in group 0). I will of course accept it anyhow.

Comment: You don't need to sort by `group_number` since the `groupby` after the `sort_values` is like a `sort_values` implicitly. You can add `group_number` to `sort_values` but it will not change the result.

Comment: @pansen - really nice solution ;)

Comment: @pansen - and one improvement should be instaed `df["group_diff"]` create Series `group_number=df.sort_values("val")...` and last `df.groupby([group_number, "group_diff"])` ;)

Comment: @jezrael I'm trying to get my head around how your suggestions improves the given solution - can you explain why?

Comment: Yes, improvement shoud be no new column only :) And it should help if is necessary remove it.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks, finally got your point :-). Added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

so you want to group together values in `val` whose difference is 1 or closer?

One thing you could do:

Assuming you have decimal numbers, you can group them by their rounded value, meaning you group them to the closest specified decimal position, using [`df.round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html), so e.g. to round them to the nearest integer:

```py
df.groupby(df["val"].round(0))
```

Since you have integers, what you could do is divide val by 2, so values who previously differed by 1 now differ by 0.5. Now you round them to the nearest integer with the above function, and you can group them that way!

Btw I dont consider this a full answer, its merely a suggestion on the topic and could be interesting to anyone finding this question