# Group/clustering(?) by custom function where values are almost the same

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'vals':[2.5, 3, 4, 2.5, 10, 11, 9], 'group':''})

   vals group
0   2.5      
1   3.0      
2   4.0      
3   2.5      
4  10.0      
5  11.0      
6   9.0
```

And want to assign each row a group where values in `vals` are very close by a function (the function is made up, more complex in reality but returning True/False):

```
def similar(val1, val2):
    if abs(val1-val2)<=3:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

So first value 2.5 should be compared to all values and if the function says True they should get the same grouping. For example similar(2.5, 3), similar(2.5, 4), similar(2.5, 2.5) all return True so they should be grouped. Then move on to 10.
To create:

```
   vals group
0   2.5   0      
1   3.0   0      
2   4.0   0      
3   2.5   0     
4  10.0   1      
5  11.0   1     
6   9.0   1
```

I've been trying something like this. But I cant get it to work and I'm thinking there must be some smarter pandas way of grouping using a function:

```
for i in df.index.tolist():
    df['group'].iloc[i] = group
    v1 = df['vals'].iloc[i]
    for j in df.index.tolist()[i+1:]:
        print(i,j)
        v2 = df['vals'].iloc[j]
        if similar(v1, v2):
            df['group'].iloc[j] = group
```

Not a very well defined problem, I know. But Im hoping someone at least can point be in some direction so I can google...

Comment: what if a number can fall into 2 groups? say you have 2.5, 4.0 and 6.5? 4 is close to 2.5, but at the same time 4 is also close to 6.5, but 2.5 is not close to 6.5. So in which group should 4.0 go? And what if there's even more complicated scenario's?

Comment: I reality all values will be in very distinct groups. So either extremely close together or very far apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sort the values, then check the [.diff()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) with the previous value, then check if this diff is larger than the max_distance with [.gt()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html#pandas.DataFrame.gt):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'vals':[2.5, 3, 4, 2.5, 10, 11, 9, 30]})
df = df.sort_values(by='vals')

max_distance = 3
df['group'] = (df
    .diff()
    .gt(max_distance)
    .cumsum()
)
```

Resulting dataframe:

```
    vals    group
0   2.5     0
1   3.0     0
2   4.0     0
3   2.5     0
4   10.0    1
5   11.0    1
6   9.0     1
7   30.0    2
```

See also for a similar answer:
[Python pandas - how to group close elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48109624/python-pandas-how-to-group-close-elements)